# SELECT rank FROM members WHERE?

Tags: php, sql

I have written an SQL query and a $_SESSION cookie called "username" basically what I am trying to do is query the database for the "logged in" users rank that is contained in the "rank" column in the "members" table of my database.

Here is my header code to check that they are actually logged in (otherwise it redirects them to the login page)

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
header("location:login/main_login.php");
}
```

AND Here is what I have so far for my query but I have absolutely no clue how to proceed in only selecting the user that is logged in. ***Note: I am aware that the query is not completed***

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT rank FROM members WHERE  ");
$userrank = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

I've also set a variable for MyRank so that I can check the users rank to display specific content. (Not sure if that really matters in terms of my query but hopefully you get the idea.)

```
$MyRank = $userrank[1]->rank;
```

**EDIT: additional information.**

So basically I am trying to display content based on what the users rank is in my database. IE) if they are an administrator I want to show specific html. If they are a user I want to show a different set of html. How I'm doing it currently (that isn't working) is by a php if statement like so:

```
if ($MyRank == "Administrator"){
            echo adminpanel();
}else if ($MyRank == "User") {
echo userpanel();
}
```

Basically the problem I'm having is that my User or Admin panels wont display unless ALL the users in my database are "Administrator" or "User". If there is an Administrator and a User in that table it will show nothing at all.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I tried to add more information as best I could. It's a weird problem to describe haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Based on guesses:**

```
$authUser = $_SESSION['username'];  // get the logged in user from session, guess this is the username

$result = $conn->query("SELECT rank FROM members WHERE username='$authUser';");
// if its userid then userid=$authUser without single quotes

$userrank = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Comment: Definitely got me a little closer. I'm getting this error:
`Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'DragonKyn' in 'where clause'` which is my users name. Meaning that it seems to be accurately finding the authorized user but not looking in the table anymore? It's treating it as a column. Here is how I have written the query as you suggested... `$result = $conn->query("SELECT rank FROM members WHERE username = $authUser");`

Comment: must be like this ... username = '$authUser' .... The search (text) value must be enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: This is an OK answer but adds in a potential SQL injection vuln. @DragonKyn, are you using parameter binding instead of the string concatenation approach shown here?